# showing error in dynamic sitemap php xml xmlParseEntityRef: no name

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sitemap

I am making a dynamic sitemap but I am getting the following error, I know the answer is already there but I am not understanding, please guide

```
error on line 68 at column 69: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
```

Here is the code what is the problem wrong

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$status=1;
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM admitcard  WHERE status=? ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare($sql1); 
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $status);
$stmt1->execute();
$admit_result = $stmt1->get_result();

?>
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");

echo '<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->'.PHP_EOL; 

echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<url>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<loc>'.$base_url.'</loc>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '</url>' . PHP_EOL;

  while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($admit_result)){
      echo '<url>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<loc>'.'localhost:8080/mysite/admitcard/'.$row2["id"].'/'.str_replace('','-',trim($row2['pagename_admit'])).'</loc>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<lastmod>'.date('c',time()).'</lastmod>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</url>' . PHP_EOL;
     }

   echo '</urlset>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

This one is running perfectly but error is showing in above script thought both of them are quite similar

```
while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($schlar_result)){

    echo '<url>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<loc>'.'https://loclhost:8080/Site/other/'.$row3["id"].'/'. str_replace(' ','-',trim($row3['pagename_schlr'])).'</loc>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<lastmod>'.date('c',time()).'</lastmod>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</url>' . PHP_EOL;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, cannot find the problem with the information in your question. Which line is 456? And are you sure that was the complete error message?

Comment: Make that line 86.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have edited error please guide

Comment: Nothing has change. It is still unclear which line generates the error and the error still looks incomplete.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware now can you find error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.